# How to controller motherboard sys fan ports through program (java,c or c++)

Tags: java, c++, c

I have a customized motherboard where 2 sys fan ports are available.

And I'm using LED FLASH Light in one port. And it continuously is on ON State. So i want to

control (ON/OFF) LED Flash light through program. I was trying to do this in java and i

didn't get any idea yet on how to do this.

If someone knows in c,c++ or java language please reply.

Thanks

Comment: "if someone know in c,c++ or java language please reply." - I do.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun - I doubt.

Comment: I would be very surprised if someone did it it pure Java. (no DLLs etc.)

Comment: Short version: Stuff like this is complicated and depends entirely on the model of motherboard, it might even be impossible. If you want to play with LEDs it might be better (and cheaper in sense of not having to spend 10s of hours for little effect) to get something like [Arduino board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) which will also let you do a whole lot more.

Comment: @Pietu1998: It would be quite easy on Linux; most of these kinds of things have an interface in `/sys`, which is quite accessible through standard `java.io`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 And what code do you think the java.io library wrapper routines call on in turn? A qualified guess would be something written in C. Indeed all kind of _wrapper functions_ can be written in pure Java :)